# Python code compiles but nothing is happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Im trying to append multiple csv files from one directory into a single file within another. When I run this code it appears to compile successfully but it does not take effect. The `combined.csv` file remains empty after each run. There are also no errors within the console. I attempted this on multiple IDEs (vs code, pycharm, and spyder).

```
import os
import glob    
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="/directoryA/directoryB/csvFile_directoryC",
                outfile="/directoryA/directoryB/combine.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    filelist=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["c1","c2","c3","c4"]
    for filename in filelist:
        print(filename)
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

Comment: You don't seem to ever call that function you defined.

Comment: Assuming that your indentation is actually correct on your end, you don't call the function.

Comment: What's the smallest example you can create which still doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not going to print anything if you didn't call it ;)

I think you just forgot to call your function in your program, that's why it is compiling, but since the function is never being called you are never getting a print.

Comment: This would have been a nice comment.

Comment: @scharette Yes but many have already commented, just put an official answer for the OP

Comment: Lol wow, I had a slow moment. Can't believe I still didn't catch it even as I typed the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's not what's been stated above (i.e. you need to call the function), you may not actually be able to find any *.csv files in that directory.  Since it's a for loop over filelist, if filelist turns up empty, you'll still be left with dfList that's an empty list, but is still valid to concat on your concatDf.

If it's not the fact that the function is never called, try printing the result from os.listdir() to see what's in there for glob to check against, and check that your filelist isn't an empty list.